# Can a label be translated or rotated with an entity?

Tags: eyeshot

I want to rotate or translate my entity, but its label cannot be moved together like an entity's sub entity. If there is no an easy way to implement this, I have got to create a point and then rotate or translate the point same way as the entity does and then dynamically create a new label based on that point.
Is there another more direct and easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Labels are defined for each Viewport.
Maybe you can store the label's *AnchorPoint* to the entity's *EntityData* property and transform it according to the entity transformation.

```
var entity = model1.Entities[0];
entity.EntityData = model1.ActiveViewport.Labels[0].AnchorPoint;

var translation = new Translation(20, 30);

entity.TransformBy(translation);
((Point3D)entity.EntityData).TransformBy(translation);

model1.Entities.Regen();
model1.Invalidate();
```